# Conexion a SQL VB.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

En una pagina simple en VB ASP.NET me da error con la conexión a SQL:

> La operación de múltiples pasos de OLE DB generó errores. Compruebe los valores de estado de OLE DB si es posible. No se realizó ningún trabajo.

soy nuevo en el lenguaje VB, dejo una muestra de mi codigo

```
 <%@ Page  aspcompat=true Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="buscar.aspx.vb" Inherits="buscador_yuyin.WebForm1" %>
```

Buscador

Resultados obtenidos con **<%=Request("Palabra") %>**

```
<% 
    Dim Conexion, Tabla

    Conexion = Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Tabla = Server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    Conexion.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TEST-PC\VIRTUAL;DATABASE=prueba;Integrated Security=True"
    Conexion.open()

    Dim Temp
    Temp = "Select * From busqueda('" & Request("palabra") & ")'"

    Tabla.Open(Temp, Conexion)

    If Tabla.BOF And Tabla.EOF Then
%> 
    <p><font face="Tahoma" size="2">No se ha encontrado nada con <strong><%=Request("palabra")%></strong> en la Base de Datos</font></p> 

<% 
    Else
%> 
   <div align="center"><center> 
   <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="74" bordercolor="#C0C0C0"> 
   <tr> 
       <td width="28%" height="19"> 
       <p align="center"><strong><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Categoria</font></strong> 
    </td> 
    <td width="28%" height="19"> 
       <p align="center"><strong><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Producto</font></strong></p> 
    </td> 
    <td width="52%" height="19"> 
       <p align="center"><strong><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Descripcion</font></strong> 
    </td> 
    <td width="19%" height="19"> 
       <p align="center"><strong><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Url</font></strong></p> 
    </td> 
   </tr> 
   <% While Not Tabla.EOF%> 
      <tr> 
       <td width="28%" bgcolor="#FFCC00" height="51"> 
          <p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><%=Tabla.Fields("Categoria")%></font></td> 
       <td width="28%" bgcolor="#FFCC00" height="51"> 
          <p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><%=Tabla.Fields("Nombre")%></font></td> 
       <td width="52%" bgcolor="#FFCC00" height="51"> 
          <p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><%=Tabla.Fields("Descripcion")%></font></td> 
       <td width="19%" bgcolor="#FFCC00" height="51"> 
          <p align="center"><a href="<%=Tabla.Fields("url")%>"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Img</font></a> 
      </tr> 
<% 
            Tabla.MoveNext
        End While
        Tabla.Close
        Conexion.Close
    End If
%> 
</table> 
</center></div> 
<p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Busquedas</font></p> 
<p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">2002</font></p> 
<p align="center"> </p> 
</body>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da?, y otra cosa, la conexión ¿no deberia estar en code behind todo eso?

Comment: el error es lo que esta como cita: La operación de múltiples pasos de OLE DB generó errores... y realmente no importa mucho que se visualice el código, realmente estoy aprendiendo, y me estoy topando con errores como estos, poco a poco los trato de pulir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy segura, pero parece que tienes un detalle en esta linea:

```
Temp = "Select * From busqueda('" & Request("palabra") & ")'"
```

aplicando la corrección:

```
Temp = "Select * From busqueda('" & Request("palabra") & "')"
```

No se si le afecte esa comilla, ¿cómo quedaría el `string` final?

```
Select * from busquedas('palabra')
```

¿Estas llamando a una función? o ¿porqué queda así?, porque si estas utilizando SQL, deberia ser algo como:

```
Select * from tabla where campo like '%texto_a_buscar%'
```

en tu caso, no sé cual el nombre del campo pero suponiendo que se llame palabra:

```
Temp = "Select * From busqueda where palabra like '%" & Request("palabra") & "%'"
```

Añado que según el error:

Se puede deber a que la conexión o el query tienen algún detalle, puede ser incongruencia entre los diferentes tipos de datos, etc., valida primero lo que te digo, si tienes el ejemplo de código para compartir, algún .zip o .rar te podría ayudar mejor.  Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es como indica Cristina, el error esta en tu consulta:

```
Temp = "Select * From busqueda('" & Request("palabra") & ")'"
```

Debería ser:

```
Temp = "Select * From Tabla Where campo = '" & Request("palabra") & "' "
```

O:

```
Temp = "Select * From Tabla Where campo Like '%" & Request("palabra") & "%' "
```